# How to access dynamic array inside a class constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, private

How do I access the dynamic array and set values to it? For example array[size] = {8, 4, 3, 2, ...}

```
class Array
{
public:
    Array(int sze)// default constructor
    {
        size = sze;
        ptr = new int [size];
    }

private:
    int size; // number of elements in the Array
    int *ptr = 0; // address of dynamically allocated memory

};

int main()
{
    Array arry(10);
    cout << arry.getSize();

    //.....;
}
```

Comment: you might consider using std::vector or another stl container instead of writing your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array that you have created is `private`, and to access it you must provide an accessor method:

```
public:
    ...
    int* getPtr() { return ptr; }
...
int *ptr = arry.getPtr();
ptr[0] = 1;
cout << ptr[0];
```

Alternatively you can hide the pointer itself and provide `get(position)` and `set(position)` methods to ensure that other code doesn't mess with your pointer.

Comment: Thank You very much. Can you help me with the += operator? I have to create two arrays and merge the values of array one into array two. For example, if array1 contains
 1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 15
and array2 contains
 3, 4, 7, 13, 19, 21, 25
then after execution of the statement
 array1 += array2
array2 will be unchanged, and array1 will contain
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25

Comment: @SaminKhan Ask another question! (Hint: += doesn't work on arrays, you have to use a loop).

Comment: @SaminKhan  If this answer solved your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark below the vote count on the left.